# Изменение волны голосового сообщения VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api

После того, как я загрузил голосовое сообщение в `ВК`, в ответ получил `JSON`:

```
{"file":"141521019|0|-1|805334|090f73dc8c|ogg|12140|audiomsgpl_141521019_********.ogg|4948747ec7f307d5d8011749d5ec15de|fdc5745c7838ddc6e5db2dc70161bb7b||||eyJhdWRpb19tc2ciOnsiZHVyYXRpb24iOjYuMDcsIndhdmVmb3JtIjoiMzI6MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDEwMDAwMTIzNjc4OTc2MjI3ZGlsbm9tamQ2MmFpcHR1dXJtZjcyOWhvc3Z2dXJtaGM2MTVhZWlsbW5ta2hlYjg0MjEyMzQzNDMzMzIyMTIxMjAyMDIxMzE0MzM0MzYzNzM4NDc1NTUifX0="}
```

Последняя часть показалась мне знакома, и я решил расшифровать её (`Base64`):

> eyJhdWRpb19tc2ciOnsiZHVyYXRpb24iOjYuMDcsIndhdmVmb3JtIjoiMzI6MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDEwMDAwMTIzNjc4OTc2MjI3ZGlsbm9tamQ2MmFpcHR1dXJtZjcyOWhvc3Z2dXJtaGM2MTVhZWlsbW5ta2hlYjg0MjEyMzQzNDMzMzIyMTIxMjAyMDIxMzE0MzM0MzYzNzM4NDc1NTUifX0=

После того как я это сделал, у меня получилось это:

```
{"audio_msg":{"duration":6.07,"waveform":"32:000000000000000010000123678976227dilnomjd62aiptuurmf729hosvvurmhc615aeilmnmkheb8421234343332212120202131433436373847555"}}
```

Получается, что `duration` - это длинна голосового сообщения (6 секунд), а `waveform` - это волна.
 Так этот документ выглядит после загрузки:
 [image: wave]
   Так к чему я клоню, можно ли после расшифровки изменить волну, потом зашифровать обратно и сохранить этот документ? А то я пытался, но у меня ничего не получалось, выдавал ошибку:

> One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: file field is
>   incorrrect!

Как-то это ведь можно изменить, ибо когда я записывал это голосовое сообщение с телефона, волна была другая, так как было много "помех", но когда я скачал его через API, волна стала куда более гладкой

Comment: Может быть вам скачать этот файл, изменить по методам вашего языка и загрузить новый? То что вы говорите это просто информация.

Comment: Кстати не поделитесь скриптом для загрузки файла? (в вашем случае голосового сообщения)